# Free software to plot cartograms

Tags: charts

Is there any free software to plot [cartograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartogram)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MAPresso](http://www.mapresso.com/) is a free Java applet for unclassed choropleth maps and cartograms.